# How do jQuery Custom events work exactly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't find any good resources on how custom events in jquery are actually implemented.  Like how they simulate the event bubbling, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This way:

```
// bubbling is internal
trigger: function( event, data, elem /*, bubbling */ ) {
// Event object or event type
var type = event.type || event,
    bubbling = arguments[3];

// Handle a global trigger
if ( !elem ) {
    // Don't bubble custom events when global (to avoid too much overhead)
    event.stopPropagation();

    // Only trigger if we've ever bound an event for it
    if ( jQuery.event.global[ type ] ) {
        jQuery.each( jQuery.cache, function() {
            if ( this.events && this.events[type] ) {
                jQuery.event.trigger( event, data, this.handle.elem );
            }
        });
    }
}

// ... snip ...
// Trigger the event, it is assumed that "handle" is a function
var handle = elem.nodeType ?
    jQuery.data( elem, "handle" ) :
    (jQuery.data( elem, "__events__" ) || {}).handle;

if ( handle ) {
    handle.apply( elem, data );
}

var parent = elem.parentNode || elem.ownerDocument;
// ... snip ....
if ( !event.isPropagationStopped() && parent ) {
    jQuery.event.trigger( event, data, parent, true );

   } else if ( !event.isDefaultPrevented() ) {
   // ... snip ...
                jQuery.event.triggered = true;
                target[ targetType ]();
    }
}
```

What's going on here is as follows:

When `trigger` is called jQuery checks to see if the event is being triggered globally (`$.trigger("event_name");`).

If it is *not* being triggered globally, *and* propagation has not been stopped **and** the element in question has a parent element (`!event.isPropagationStopped() && parent`) then jQuery calls the trigger event manually on the parent element.

```
jQuery.event.trigger( event, data, parent, true );
```

There is quite a bit more going on -- see [event.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js) in the jQuery source code.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [tutorials](http://weblog.bocoup.com/publishsubscribe-with-jquery-custom-events)

```
$(document).bind("eventType", ...);
// This is equivalent to the plugin's $.subscribe("eventType", ...);
$(document).trigger("eventType");
// equivalent to plugin's $.publish("eventType");
```

Also checkout this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815809/how-to-make-live-custom-events-in-jquery)

Comment: I think he didn't want an API explanation but a technical explanation on how they actually work.

Comment: @ThiefMaster If that's the case, best way to learn is to look at the source :) http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/