# livequery performance

Tags: jquery, livequery

I've recently [discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797199/bind-jquery-method-to-html-loaded-through-an-ajax-call/4797402#4797402) that livequery plugin for jQuery may be quite wasteful, as it does not use event delegation but binds all bindable events and re-checks the whole DOM on each change

if anyone has more information or suggestions on best practices using livequery and .live(), I would be very grateful

Comment: As noted in the answer by "patrick dw" below, the .live() and .delegate() pretty much are integration by the same author of livequery into the core - see his blog here: http://brandonaaron.net/blog at least as I understand it :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is rare that you would actually need a plugin like `livequery`. Probably the only time you really need it is if you need to react to changes to the DOM made by some other jQuery code that you *can not modify*.

While `.live()` does use event delegation, it does it on the `document` level, which means that it needs to process *all* events on the page to see if they match the selectors provided per event type.

A better alternative (IMO) to both of those is the [`delegate()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method which uses event delegation just like `.live()`, but lets you constrain it to a specific portion of the page.

```
$('#someContainer').delegate('a.someButton', 'click', function() {
    // do something when an "a.someButton" inside "#someContainer" is clicked
});
```

Note that event delegation methods respond to browser events, not to changes to the DOM. If you need to run some code based on a change to the DOM you've made, you need to run that code *when you make that alteration* to the DOM.

Comment: This is a great answer, but keep in mind that this approach will only work for events that bubble up. Some events, such as 'invalid' (fired when a form element fails validation) do not bubble up, and thus cannot be captured via delegation.