# Possible performance issue when using too many livequery

Tags: jquery, html, performance

As title says, is there any issue?

for example, i use them this way:

```
$("abbr.timeago").livequery(function() {
    $(this).timeago();
});

$("#btnPhoto").livequery(function() {
    createUploader();
});

$("#inputTagline").livequery(function () {
    $(this).charCount();
});;
```

**EDIT**
[image]
My web page alone uses up 100k memory. 
Provided page contents are generated by ajax, does anyone of you know how to solve the .timeago() problem? I really appreciate that. Thanks

**UPDATE**
Now i can get rid of livequery by @Linas answe below. **Any better answers are welcome!**

Comment: Possible duplicate [livequery performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818020/livequery-performance).

Comment: Better delegate / live, but what is your project? It always depends on your needs.

Comment: why downvote? i just want opinion T_T ..... jquery.timeago(); needs livequery to detect dynamically generated element. that's why i use it. i know about jquery.on but it needs some events to occur eg, "click".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on similar project as yours, and i also use time ago plugin, so i was facing same issue as you do right now.

What i did is i made a helper function, which does various stuff like updates time, removes unused content and so on. So instead of using livequery i simply call that helper function when i update any content on my page and so saving a lot of memory.

**EDIT**
It's just a very simple function that you create for your self:

```
function helper(){
   //update all time that exists on current page
   //just put same class name in each time object for example class="time_ago"
   //now it will update each object with class "time_ago"
   $(".time_ago").timeago();
   //now do some other stuff like remove old content unbind events and so on here...
}
```

And every time you use some kind of function which updates your content via ajax after it just call `helper()` and it will take care of things that you need, no need to worry about plugins, and their performance since you have full control over your script.

Comment: I can't get what helper function you are using, please don mind to give a short example. XD btw, i guess: you call the helper function to update "blablabla" when jquery.on is called? am i right?